# Storing Large JSON (size > 16 MB) into MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, gridfs, mongoimport

I am not able to import a large JSON (size ~70MB) into MongoDB due to the max 16 MB size constraint.

Using GridFS I was able to upload the JSON into MongoDB but not able to retrieve data in plain text format (JSON data) as GridFS stores in binary chunks.
Record in fs.chunks is in below format:

```
{
"_id":"<ObjectId>",
"files_id":"<ObjectId>",
"n":"<num>",
"data":"Binary(<Binary Data>)"
}
```

Now my question is 
1) How to decode & read data in `data:Binary(<Binary Data>)` ? 
2) Is GridFS is the best option for storing large JSON? I found mostly multimedia are stored in MongoDB using GridFS.

If there is any best option, please let me know.

Comment: Is that JSON a single document that is 70MB?

Comment: Yes, it is a single document JSON. That's the problem for splitting into smaller JSONs.

Answer (score 3):

GridFS provides APIs for reading the files. The APIs vary across drivers.

If you wish to perform queries on the data (i.e. do anything other than read back the file as you stored it) you will need to break it up into smaller pieces.

Comment: OK, that means GridFS should be used only for uploading and downloading (reading after that)?

Comment: There are several supported operations, see for example https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-gridfs/.

Comment: How to break the JSON considering it is single document json.